# Maven Dependencies that read property files

Tags: java, dropwizard

I have a java project named dbstuff which reads properties from `db.properties` with `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/db.properties")`. The values are things like connection strings, etc. This dbstuff is used in various projects most of them are web.

I now have a dropwizard project (maven) which uses `dbstuff.jar` as a dependency, this project is compiled as a fat jar as described [here](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/getting-started/#building-fat-jars), at the moment the dbstuff only read values from `db.properties` if the file is present in `/src/main/resources`, and when the package is created the `db.properties` becomes embedded in the jar.

What i want to achieve is to make `db.properties` external, so that i can have various `db.properties` (one for each environment) but only one dropwizard jar, is this possible?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass in the path to the external `db.properties` file at runtime via a system property, e.g.:

```
java -jar myjar.jar -DdbConfig=/path/to/db.properties
```

Then in your code within `dbstuff.jar` you can load the properties file:

```
final String path = System.getProperty("dbConfig");
final Properties properties = Properties.load(new FileInputStream(path));
```

Alternatively, as you've mentioned you are using Dropwizard, within your configuration file (the yaml file or whatever you are using) have a property which specifies where the external `db.properties` file is, load the properties during server initialisation and then pass them on to whatever requires it in `dbstuff.jar`.

You could then take this a step further, forget about the `db.properties` file and have an entire section in your Dropwizard config that specifies all the properties, e.g.:

```
db:
    url: jdbc://....
    user: dbuser
    # etc...
```

And then pass on what the objects in the `dbstuff.jar` need. See Dropwizard's [configuration documentation](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/manual/core/#configuration) for more information on how to do this.

Comment: thanks for the answer. The first solution is good but i'm still stuck with the web projects (served by apache, that have db.properties) that use dbstuff. Taking it a little further to the yml config, will make dbstuff to work only with the dropwizard project.

Comment: as Jonathan suggested, i will use a system property passed as argument in command-line for each environment, and in dbstuff.jar will make a small add in the code, so, if the System Property exists it will override the getResourceAsStream. this way both (web that rely on getResourceAsStream, and the dropwizard) projects will work

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a configuration class in DropWizard and then use it to return the correct configuration for each environment - https://dropwizard.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/hibernate.html.

As for your question, if you have multiple resources on the same path, even if on different jars, there is no guarantee of which one Java will be using. When you add a file named db.properties to /src/main/resources, it becomes the resource "db.properties", and is read as such:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)